# renew a SSL cert on IIS6?

Tags: installation, certificate, ssl-certificate

This question is active at https://serverfault.com/questions/67844/renew-a-ssl-cert-on-iis6.  Thanks.

---

My manager ordered a new wild card cert for our website as our current is expiring in a few days.  Now, I am stuck as I cannot figure out how to install it?  It is a cert from GoDaddy.com.  I have downloaded it to my server.  Upon unzipping it I have a PB7 file (intermediate cert) and a CRT file.

I open IIS6, click Properties on the website I want to update (it already has the old SSL Cert on it).  Click on the Directory Security tab then the Server Certificate... button.

Now, I am presented with the following options:

- Renew the current certificate - was
  done manually through GoDaddy and no
  pending renewal was ever issued.
- Remove the current certificate - does not sound right for us.
- Replace the current certificate - possible...
- Export the current certificate to a .pfx file
- Copy or move the current certificate to a remote server site

Now, when I choose the REPLACE option it presents me with a dialog of *already installed certs*!!!  My new one is not in there.

What the heck do I do?  Google/Bing is being of no help to me right now.

Comment: Keith, try on serverfault.com, you'll probably find a better audience for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/67844/renew-a-ssl-cert-on-iis6

This leads to https://serverfault.com/questions/68165/peers-certificate-has-been-revoked

And all is quite on the western front.  :(